# facebook cordova plug-in not work on local host when using web-broswer

Tags: javascript, android, html, facebook, cordova

i use facebook cordova plug-in. i try to get name of user to display on my other html page. but some how this isn't work. i don't ever got to log in to facebook

```
function Login()
{
        facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit();
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(["user_birthday","public_profile","email"]);
        facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me/?fields=name", ["user_birthday","public_profile","email"],
    function (result) {
        document.location.href = "./customer.html#"+String(result.name);
        /* alerts:
            {
                "id": "000000123456789",
                "email": "myemail@example.com"
            }
        */
    },
    function (error) {
        alert("Failed: " + error);
    });


}
```

also if i remove facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(); and emulate it on android. it go to log in on facebook but after is done the page don't change at all

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the JavaScript console? Have you initialized the plugin correctly and set your application up correctly?

Comment: no errors, initialized the plugin correctly, but i don't sure about set up